# Assert values in xml file with Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I am trying to create a Groovy Script that will assert value in certain fields in a xml response file after I execute a test case with SoapUI. I have searched for a solution regarding this and I have found that I need to define first the file which should be something like :

```
String fileContents = new File('/path/to/file').getText('UTF-8')
```

After that unfortunately I don't know how to define the separate tags so I would need your help :) Please, can you tell me how I can define and assert the fields?

Thank you!

Comment: use xmlslurper or xmlparser for xml file process.

Comment: Can you paste a sample code if it is not a problem for you that I can use as an example?

Comment: See the Groovy doc for processing xml [Link](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html). To get a value at a tag in xml refer `Gpath` in doc